VS Code won't start in WSL due to missing files
Earlier today, I had opened a window in VS Code in WSL. A few hours later, I tried again, but it crashed. At first I figured it was because the first window was still open, and while it did seem odd to me because that's not usually an issue, I closed the first window and tried again. It still failed to start, with the error message mentioning
/home/bbrk24/.vscode-server/bin/89de5a8d4d6205e5b11647eb6a74844ca23d2573/node: not found

So, I booted VS Code in Windows, noted the Node version it was using there (20.9.0), and put that version of Node for Linux at that location. Now, I get an error about a missing package.json:
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1051
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '../package.json'
Require stack:
- /home/bbrk24/.vscode-server/bin/89de5a8d4d6205e5b11647eb6a74844ca23d2573/out/server-cli.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1048:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:901:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
    at out-build/bootstrap-amd.js (/home/bbrk24/.vscode-server/bin/89de5a8d4d6205e5b11647eb6a74844ca23d2573/out/server-cli.js:4:11078)
    at /home/bbrk24/.vscode-server/bin/89de5a8d4d6205e5b11647eb6a74844ca23d2573/out/server-cli.js:1:132
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/bbrk24/.vscode-server/bin/89de5a8d4d6205e5b11647eb6a74844ca23d2573/out/server-cli.js:4:12186)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/bbrk24/.vscode-server/bin/89de5a8d4d6205e5b11647eb6a74844ca23d2573/out/server-cli.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v20.9.0

For the sake of completeness, I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.3 in WSL2 on Windows 11 Home 23H2. I have VS Code 1.90.0 and no updates are available.
What happened, and how do I fix it?

Deleting the broken ~/.vscode-server will cause VS Code to reinstall itself in WSL on next launch. Still no idea how it happened but deleting the whole folder fixed it.
As a caution, this will also delete all your extensions and you will have to reinstall them.
